# Laravel: Customize the request flow

Tags: php, yii, request, laravel-5.1

Within my app ("BIRD3"), I have a NodeJS server that uses the hprose RPC system to talk to a PHP server to query it run a request and return the result (the PHP server is multi-process and spawns a sub-process per request - for now). This proposes a few difficulties; headers, cookies, sessions.

In my Yii1 based app, I used an in-development branch of the `runkit` extension. But, as you can tell, this is super hacky, not clean, and dependency-wise, not a smart idea. But it worked, for the most part. Here is a snippet from that very bit of code I did:

```
<?php
// Header.
runkit_function_redefine("headers_sent", '', 'return false;');
runkit_function_redefine(
    "header", '$to,$replace=false,$status=200',
    'return HttpResponse::header($to);'
);
// We have a custom handler.
runkit_function_redefine(
    "setcookie",
    '$name,$value,$expire=0,$path="/",$domain=null,$secure=false,$httponly=false',
    'return HttpResponse::setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$domain,$secure,$httponly);'
);
// Because...
runkit_function_redefine(
    "session_regenerate_id",
    '$deleteOld=false',
    'return bird3_session_regenerate_id($deleteOld);'
);
```

Now, why did I need this? Simple: Yii does not have a direct way to override Session/Header/Cookie management without doing a good load of wiring of the internals. Overriding internal dependencies with extended, derived classes is not very easy and bulks up the config file a lot.

So my question is:
Does Laravel give me the possibility to extend a few classes, override methods that do Session and Header and Cookie management and enhance it to use my custom functions instead?

Comment: You can replace service providers in Laravel pretty easily, but they generally still need to either extend or implement the same interfaces as the original methods.

Comment: @samlev I figured as much. But which are the ones I need to extend/replace? That is where I seem to be stuck at.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/illuminate/session and http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#adding-custom-session-drivers - make sure that you're not replicating an existing session driver, and then follow the documentation to create a new driver if required.

Comment: @samlev Cool, that one seems to cover my needs regarding sessions. But how about header handling? As the headers are stored internally so they can be returned to the RPC system to the actual webserver, I can not soley rely on `header()`, obviously. So, how do I work out this part?

Comment: Which one do you call "an in-development branch of the runkit extension"?

Comment: @DmitryZenovich It _was_ `1.0.0-dev`. But it's on PECL now, so it's stable. That event developed just a bit before or after i posted this question.